# reading lines from txt file into .csv

Tags: batch-file, csv, ffmpeg

i have a .TXT file i created via batch file using ffmpeg. it returns the following info ( more but trying to make short)

```
major_brand=isom 
minor_version=512 
compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41 
creation_time=1970-01-01 00:00:00 
encoder=Lavf53.19.0 
genre=sport 
track=1 
title=IRWX_TV_Vol_01_1_Pt_4 
episode_id=0101
```

the .TXT file comes back with 3  of these above.  well i want to be able to only use some of the info above and then i want to create a .CSV file so that i can load into .XLS file

I have used the following and it's close:

```
REM now lets get info we need from result.txt
pause 

REM checks how many times finds genre and loops that many times
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('findstr "genre" result.txt') DO (
for %%f in (result.txt) do (
    set i=0

for /F "delims= tokens=2,3*" %%l in (%%f) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set line!i!=%%l

)
echo  !line9!, !line6!, !line8!,  >> result.csv
)
) 
pause
```

and this is coming back with the following:

```
 title=IRWX_TV_Vol_01_1_Pt_4 , genre=sport, episode_id=0101
 title=IRWX_TV_Vol_01_1_Pt_4 , genre=sport, episode_id=0101
 title=IRWX_TV_Vol_01_1_Pt_4 , genre=sport, episode_id=0101
```

ONLY the 1st video title from .TXT  file and not each of them

AND i would prefer it to come back like this:

```
 IRWX_TV_Vol_01_1_Pt_4,sport,0101
```

Minus the variables, the "=" and the space issues you see above.

i have been going over and over this trying different things and it is just not working.

Hopefully someone here can see the issue and help out, Thanks

Comment: This is particularly easy if you process each log portion individually, instead of 3 sets at the one time.  Does your batch file allow you to process the log in between files, so you can process just one set of info at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions assume all three values are present for all instances.

Assuming you never have `!` character in your file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>result.csv (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (result.txt) do (
    set "%%A=%%B"
    if %%A equ episode_id echo !title!,!genre!,!episode_id!
  )
)
```

If you do have to worry about `!` in your file:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

>result.csv (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (result.txt) do (
    set "%%A=%%B"
    if %%A equ episode_id (
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
      echo !title!,!genre!,!episode_id!
      endlocal
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: this works great but how do i get rid of the space at the end of each one?

Answer (score 1):

just use built-in `arrays`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in (result.txt) do (
    if "%%a"=="major_brand" set /a varcnt+=1
    set "%%a!varcnt!=%%b"
)
for /l %%a in (1 1 %varcnt%) do echo(!title%%a!,!genre%%a!,!episode_id%%a!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a way to do that in a batch file, but since none of the batchfile gods have chimed in , I've provided a VBSCript alternative - I personally think VBScript might be easier. So anyway, I've made assumptions based on your original question:

1. It looks like there's a maximum number of 9 lines per record (used for boundary testing)
2. You want to loop through multiple records within a single file: result.txt
3. You want to extract three lines per record into a csv type file for later use in excel.

I have set the script to strip "genre=" "title=" and "episode_id=" when it writes to the output file. It also should return results within the csv as follows:

sport,IRWX_TV_Vol_01_1_Pt_4,0101

Save this code as results.vbs or something in the same directory as your result.txt file (or update the location listed under inputFileName / outputfilename) and run from a command prompt like this:

> C:\Directoryname\path> cscript results.vbs

Flow:

1. The script tries to open up "result.txt"
2. It then loops through the entire file, searching for each required variable sequentially (It will start looking for Genre, then it will look for title and then episode_id.
3. As the script builds the results, once it has found episode_id, it writes the record details it found to results.csv and resets back to searching for genre.
4. If the script advances past genre but has not found a title line after nine lines of text, it assumes that the record is invalid and resets the scan back to genre (I hope that makes sense).

### Results.vbs

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1, ForAppending = 8
Dim fso, objFile, inputFileName, outputFilename, vars, countflag, strData, linData, recCount, linCount

' Customizable variables ---------------------
inputFilename  = "result.txt"
OutputFilename = "result.csv"
vars = Array("genre", "title", "episode_id")
recCount = 9    ' Max of 9 lines to check until reset (incase of invalid record)
' ---------------------------------------------------------

countflag = 0
linCount = 1
lindata = ""
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(inputFileName, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   strData = objFile.ReadLine

   If InStr(LCase(strData), LCase(vars(countflag))) Then
       strdata = Mid(strData, Len(vars(countflag))+2, Len(strData)-2)
       lindata = lindata & Trim(strdata) & ","
       countflag = countflag + 1
   End If
   lincount = lincount + 1
   If countflag > ubound(vars) then
       countflag = 0
       lincount = 1
       WriteText OutputFilename, Mid(linData, 1, Len(linData)-1)
       linData = ""
   Else
       If linCount > recCount Then
          countflag = 0
          linCount = 1
          lindata = ""
       End If
   End If
Loop
objFile.Close

Function WriteText(strFile, oText)
    Dim outFile
    set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForAppending, True)   
    outfile.Writeline (oText)
    outfile.Close
End Function
```

Comment: thanks question, i have never did anything with vbscript, i will give it a try, i am really hoping for a .bat file so i can make and .exe file out of it too, can that be done with this language?

Will work on this in the morning!

Comment: I see.. Well you can try using HtwoO from source forge to convert it to an exe - http://sourceforge.net/projects/htwoo/files/htwoo-version-3/ even though it says python, it supposedly does vbscript as well. The link for the vbscript download is http://sourceforge.net/projects/htwoo/files/htwoo-version-3/htwoo-vbscript-compiler-version-3-0-0-by-hadi-kiamarsi.zip/download

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (result.txt) do (
   set $test=%%a
   set %%a
   if /i "!$test:~0,10!"=="episode_id" echo !title!, !genre!, !episode_id!)
endlocal
```